# How was the Soul Stone returned?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

How was the Soul Stone returned to Vormir by

> Captain America after he traveled back in time?

And was its former keeper,

> the Red Skull

freed after someone took the Stone or did he stay around like a store manager waiting in case someone came for a refund?

Comment: With no obvious way to leave the planet, I'm assuming he's just stuck there.

Comment: I like to think Cap landed at the foot of the mountain like everyone else, but then just tossed the stone up into the air and thwacked it with his shield, right into Schmidt’s face on the peak just as he was packing up his spare shawls to leave.

Comment: I feel they rushed this part and hoped no one would notice

Comment: Stuck it in an envelope with the words “ return to sender “ and have it to red skull.

Answer (score 12):

The instruction Banner gives to Steve is pretty clear.

> **Bruce:** ...*Remember, you have to **return the stones to the exact moment you got 'em** or you're gonna open up a bunch of nasty alternative realities*

Which implies that he would return the Soul Stone to its previous resting place (care of the Red Skull) **a few seconds** after Clint received it. Red Skull would still be waiting at the top of the cliff.

> *"Red Skull would probably put the Soul Stone back to its location, and
> wait for the next unfortunate Stone seeker to make sacrifice. Cap and
> Red Skull probably won't fight. It's because it's his mission to
> return the stone to its original place. The Red Skull is also no
> longer the same Red Skull from CA. He is more like a ghost, you could
> almost say he's a completely different entity now. He only exists to
> guard the Stone, his past conscious may or may not exist anymore"*
>
> <sub><sup>[The 17 questions most wanted to know in "Avengers 4", we asked the director Russo Brothers](https://ent.qq.com/a/20190429/007983.htm) - (in translation)</sup></sub>

It's not really clear whether someone taking the stone would unbind the Red Skull from the temple *per se*, but it certainly seems that whatever happens next would take more than a single "moment".

Comment: Too bad Cap couldn't exchange the Soul stone for ***'s soul back, since her body would presumably still be present at the bottom of the drop point at the time Cap returned the stone.

Comment: I think the emphasize is on "nasty" in Bruce's quote. Some of the stones cannot just be put back. For example the tesseract was destroyed, Cap can only bring back the plain space stone.

Comment: According to the official Avengers Twitter, Red Skull was freed when Thanos acquired the Soul Stone: https://twitter.com/Avengers/status/1025583604305256448

Comment: @Raj - But was he 'unfreed' when Captain America turned up a microsecond later and put it back where it was before.,

Comment: @Valorum you're most likely correct, but has that actually been stated by anyone involved?

Comment: @Raj - That was the entire plan, approved by the Sorceror Supreme herself.

Comment: @Valorum I expect Cap returned the soul stone to the exact moment when Clint received the soul stone, not when Thanos received the soul stone. Also, Thanos' receiving of the soul stone already freed Red Skull. As Banner had already explained, that moment in time can not be changed.

Comment: @Chris It may be notable that the "nasty" is probably influenced by the Ancient One and the Time Stone, who may know explicitly that the Time Stone is needed to save her alternate timeline from Dormammu.

Comment: @Valorum By the Sorcerer Surpreme himself, you mean.  The Ancient One did not approve.  She simply trusted in the judgment of her successor, once that implicit judgment was revealed to her.

Comment: I, for one, would have liked to see the Cap/Schmidt rematch, thank you very much.

Comment: @Chris - He has the Time and Space stones. This means he can go anywhere in the universe and reverse the flow of time on the various objects the stones were housed in

Comment: In a recent Q&A, Joe Russo explained: "Red Skull would probably put the soul stone back to its location, and wait for the next unfortunate stone seeker to make sacrifice. Cap and Red Skull probably won't fight. It's because it's his mission to return the stone to its original place. The Red Skull is also no longer the same Red Skull from FA. He is more like a ghost, you could almost say he's a completely different entity now. He only exists to guard the stone, his past conscious may or may not exist anymore."  He may have been freed later when Thanos took the stone, but apparently not in 2014.

Comment: Link for prior comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bj0it4/joe_russos_qa_about_the_plot_of_avengers_endgame/

Comment: @Rob - Cheers. The translation is a bit choppy, but I'm happy to add it to my answer :-)

Comment: @Valorum well probably he can't, but The Ancient One can probably help.

Comment: Check my answer out, we found out how he can return the Stone now apparently.

Answer (score 8):

[Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211069/58193) does a good job of explaining why Red Skull would likely still be on Vormir and that the two wouldn't fight. However, it doesn't explain how the Soul Stone is returned. Markus and McFeely were asked that question for the HeroBlend podcast, here is their response:

> Stephen McFeely: It's a good question. I think it is an everlasting exchange.
>
> Christopher Markus: There's a slot.
>
> Stephen McFeely: That's right. Yeah, that's right. It's like an old time bank. It's a pneumatic tube.
>
> Christopher Markus: You put it back, but you don't get anything in return. It's not like a pawn shop.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, How Does One Return The Soul Stone? We Asked The Avengers: Endgame Writers](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2471443/how-does-one-return-the-soul-stone-we-asked-the-avengers-endgame-writers)</sub>